# How to count nodes with property enabled?

Tags: angular, typescript

I have a tree with Node object:

```
class Node implements ITreeNode {
  id?: any;
  name: string;
  children:? Node[],
  enabledState = new Subject<boolean>();

  toggle() {
    this.enabled = !this.enabled;
    this.enabledState.next(this.enabled);
  }
}
```

I want to know how much Nodes were enabled(selected). After each selection I push state. But how to count all enabled nodes in the tree? I think it is bad to idea to subscribe to all nodes.

Comment: Is `children` property recursively an array of type of the enclosing `Node` class? That also happen to contain a `Subject`? This look like bad design.

Comment: https://dev.to/krumpet/getting-a-recursive-data-structure-asynchronously-with-rxjs-46b9

Comment: Yes, children has `Node[]` And each Node has Subject

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What it´s "ITreeNode" in your code?

You can do something similar to this code:

```
public getEnableds(): number {
     let count = this.enabled ? 1 : 0;
     this.children(s).map(x => count += x.getEnableds());
     return count;
}
```

Comment: I'd say a forEach would be better.

Comment: Also this method needs to be public.

Comment: That´s true, private changed to public. forEach it´s better (avoid create others arrays), but if we want the best performance, reduce could be the best option. I think @MamaBaba has understood the concept